# Complex Form elements alignment

Tags: html, css

I'm using primeng css and I want to button and inputs to be aligned (end) horizontally  [image] **I don't want to be aligned labels with button**

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tdug0ea3/)

```
<div class="ui-g ui-fluid dashboard">
    <div class="ui-g-12">
        <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-2">
            <label for="year"> Year</label>
            <input type="text" name="year" >
        </div>
         <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-2">
            <label for="month"> Month</label>
            <input type="text" name="month" >
        </div>
        <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-1">
            <input type="button" value="Search" id="myButton">
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As a fullstack dev you should be an expert in frontend as well as backend. But everybody just throws this word around anyway.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I align input field and submit button (also differences between: IE, FFox, Chrome)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073766/how-do-i-align-input-field-and-submit-button-also-differences-between-ie-ffox)

Comment: @Mär I removed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the align-self-end class (bootstrap 4 / flexbox) to vertically align the button to the bottom of the column.

```
<div class="form-group col-md-2 align-self-end"><button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn" name="btn" type="submit">Submit</button></div>
```

Also visit [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40878566/align-button-with-input-forms-with-labels) for further query

You can also use `align-self: flex-end;`

**Use it on your Compiler not on Fiddle**

Comment: and must be display:flex in the parent div

Comment: Yup sorry I forget to write it. Glad to see its work